# Unable to format/parse this date

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have a date that looks like this:

```
Thu May 21 2015 10:28:49 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

It is coming from fullCalendar.getDate()

I need to format/parse dates in this format to something like mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

As fullcalendar uses moment js [ http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/date_formatting_string/ ], you can try the below code.. If you have not included moment js..include it and then try..

```
moment(fullCalendar.getDate()).format("mm/DD/YYYY");
```

Comment: I tried to include moment.js and attempt this, but it wan't working. Anyways I found a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I actually just stumbled upon this through a google search, even though I didnt find it through searching their docs:

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, formatString [, options ] )
```

This worked for me, Thanks